# Skrill payment gateway : How to pay using card instead of "skrill Digital Wallet"?

Tags: payment-gateway

I am using skrill payment gateway in my website and I want that user will pay with their CreditCard. I have set up payment_method="ACC" but after that it need to signup. Please take a look of below code what is going wrong with it:

```
<form action="https://pay.skrill.com" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="xxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com">
<input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="http://xxxxxxx.com/design/skrill/verify.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://xxxxxxx.com/design/skrill/thanks.php"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="39.60">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="Description:">
<input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="Romeo and Juliet (W.Shakespeare)">
<input type='hidden' name='hide_login' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name="payment_methods" value="ACC">
<input type="submit" value="Pay!">
</form>
```

Note: i have made a testing with both payment_method and payment_methods

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I want to setup that user can show only pay with credit/debit card instead of "Skrill Digital Wallet" so user don't need an account on skrill, they can pay as a guest direct through card. But it is showing "Skrill Digital Wallet"